# javafx unresolved location of an imageView

Tags: scenebuilder, javafx-11

so I am working with scene builder and I added an imageView to the anchor pane , and I used a picture inside it , but it keeps showing this yellow alert , I don't know if it is an error or not , will it affect my project ? how can I get rid of it ?
[image]

Comment: Is the Image a file outside of the project structure? My guess is that the image is not where it originally was. Put the image in the appropriate location inside the project.